# How do I include the Category URL Title in the Channel Entry link

Tags: categories

I am pulling a series of entries from a Channel that has about a dozen categories. I need to be able to direct each entry's "read more" link to a template group that bears the same name as the category_url_title. I have reviewed the entries here and the ee documentation, but I can't figure out how to pull that information in using the channel entries tag.

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="features"}
  {summary} <a href="{category_url_title}">read more"</a>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

What is the correct way to "pull" the category from the entry and reference it there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Category variables are only available within the `{categories}` loop.

```
{categories limit="1"}{category_url_title}{/categories}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also found that if you're trying obtain the category_url_title of a related entry, it can be done like this:

```
{related-products:categories limit="1"}{category_url_title}{/related-products:categories}
```